# Webcam issue: Logitech Quickcam Chat

Tags: usb, video, webcam, logitech, cheese

I'm having a problem getting my webcam, a logitech quickcam chat, to work with Ubuntu 20.04; it shows up in lsusb and as /dev/video1 just fine, and I can get it to show a picture in Guvcview and VLC, which leads me to assume it's at least somewhat UVC-compliant. The problem is, it will not work with any other application I try, including Cheese, Firefox and Discord. Any ideas at all on how I could fix this. I appreciate it's an old camera and there's only so much you can do with kernel-driven hardware, but any help would be nice.